# ANGULAR: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, filtering

I am trying to filter my array by using modula on the id by clicking a button. Searching on the internet i am using pipe for it. But i get a error that it "pipe" does not exist. I don't know why? Just by using .filter() without the pipe wouldn't work and with it doesn't either. Or am i just going in the wrong direction for a simple onclick filter. I am quite a beginner to angular.

this is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { StreamService } from '../stream.service';
import { Stream } from '../stream';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-discover',
  templateUrl: './discover.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discover.component.scss']
})
export class DiscoverComponent implements OnInit {
  streams!: Stream[];
  
  constructor(private streamService: StreamService) { 
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getStreams();
  }

  getStreams(){
    this.streamService.getStream().subscribe((data =>{
      this.streams = data;
      console.log(this.streams);
    }))
  }


  filterIsUneven(){
  this.streams.pipe(map((streams => streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)))
  };

}
```

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="buttons">
    <button (click) = "filterIsUneven()"> Games </button>
    <button> Music </button>
    <button> Esports </button>
    <button> IRL </button>
    <button>Back</button>
  </div>

  <div class="streams" *ngFor="let stream of streams">
    <h3>{{stream.id}}</h3>
    <h3>{{stream.title}}</h3>
    <img src="{{stream.thumbnailUrl}}">
  </div>

</div>
```

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Stream } from './stream';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StreamService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getStream():Observable<Stream[]>{
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos");
  }

getLiveStream(id:number):Observable<Stream[]> {
  const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1/photos?id=${id}`;
  return this.http.get<Stream[]>(url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set this.streams inside of get streams the type of this.streams is not an observable, but rather Stream[]. So when you call filterIsUneven() you cannot use the pipe method on streams since it is not an observable. Instead use this logic:

```
filterIsUneven(){
  this.streams.filter(stream => stream.id % 3)
 };
```

Comment: i already tried that, when i use that logic i get an "ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. That's why i thought the pipe would help.

Comment: How large is this array?

Comment: 50 objects in it

Comment: The error: "ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" makes me think something is either not written correctly or something is some how being called in an infinite loop. Based on what code you're showing this should be happening. Next steps would be add a debugger inside `filterIsUneven()` to see how many times its being called.